# How to assign the new clusters using kkmeans (kernlab package)

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means

The function `kkmeans` from the `kernlab`package peform the Kernl K-Means in a specific dataset. However, when I run the function it's only give me back the centers, the clustersize and the Within-cluster sum of squares. Here's an example

```
library(kernlab)
test<-kkmeans(as.matrix(iris[,-5]),3)
test
```

But I'm interested in the clustermemberships classify of each observation. Someone knows how to store that values in a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the `test` variable you'll see that the cluster memberships are stored in the `.Data` component. You can access it using the following:

```
cluster_membership <- test@.Data
print(cluster_membership)
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2
[75] 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3
[149] 3 2
```

You can use the test variable itself for plotting purposes if you wish, however, since it extends the `vector` class as a `specc` object:

```
plot(iris, col=test)
```

[image: kkmeans plot]